# The extent of the usage of DDM formula by the big boys

Tags: equities, valuation

I am wondering to which extent versions of the DDM formula(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_discount_model) is used by large banks and institutional investors etc, in some sense anyone who is not a retail investor.

Comment: @noob2 just to get a grip on the credability of this answer, do you mind telling me how you know this?

Comment: @noob2 that does it, thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDM definitely used in practice. Probably the Two Stage Dividend Discount model is used more often that the 1 stage or Gordon model described in the Wikipedia article.

From time to time there are surveys of techniques used by equity analysts, for example *Equity Valuation: A Survey of Professional Practice* by G. Pinto (2005), SSRN [2657717](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2657717). You can see some figures concerning DDM on Page 5 and on Page 17, or read the entire report for more details. It may not be the most popular technique but is used in a substantial number of cases.